# Create Zoom link shortcut

Tags: calendar, automation, zoom.app

I am looking for a way to automatically add a Zoom link to my meetings which I create with Apple calendar.
The option to add a video conference seems to be for FaceTime only.

Is there a way to automatically create a Zoom link via keyboard shortcut and paste it to the calendar's text body?

Answer (score 1):

You can paste a zoom link directly into the Location field and it will be a "hot link" to click on at the time of the meeting. Alternatively you can paste the zoom link to the Notes part of the appointment and it will also be a hot link. If you have a personalized meeting id, you can make it a text replacement and literally just type in your short cut and it will expand to create your link <--- fastest. If I type "meetingid" in the location field or the notes field of an event, it expands to meeting id: https://us02web.zoom.us/j/4151234567 . So fab!

Comment: For me, even if I write down zoom link on Apple Calendar, it does not become hot link. I have to copy it and paste it on browser to open it